# How to create a site using SFRA but name and ID would be my custom name and ID

Tags: demandware

Whenever I am creating a site following the steps in SFCC infocentre I am getting two sites with name as RefArch and RefArchGlobal but I want my site with my id and my name, I was able to do that by creating a custom site and then assigning the same catalog as RefArch and also the same content libraries as RefArch and then by importing the slot config of Refarch to my custom site, I want to know if there is any other way of doing it easily.

Thanks,
Faizen

Answer (score 1):

You can pull on your local -> [Storefront Reference Architecture Data](https://github.com/SalesforceCommerceCloud/storefrontdata). This is a repository for the RefArch site data that goes with Storefront Reference Architecture (SFRA). After:

1. Clean up the `demo_data_sfra` folder by removing what you don't need. An example is all related to `RefArchShared` site if you need just
   `RefArch`
2. Replace in the XML files `RefArch` with your site ID
3. Rename folder names in the `sites` with proper site names.
4. Rename catalogs and make a proper link between them.
5. Cross check all files to see if there are other references. For example, in the `jobs.xml` you might have a site context and you need to use a proper site ID there.

After all those steps, archive and import the site to your sandbox. Run reindex and clean cache and check storefront. It should work.